# Can a YN-E3-RT control a Phottix Laso Receiver?

Tags: canon, yongnuo, phottix

Does someone know if this combo is possible? I have bought YN-E3-RT and a pair of YN-E3-RX to trigger a 580EX II and a 430EX II. I also have 580EX that I want to include in the system. So I was wondering if the YongNuo YN-E3-RT is able to trigger the Laso receiver which I'm planning to mount my 580EX.

It's just unfortunate that I can't use my old 580EX.

Comment: Why not just use another YN-E3-RX for the 580EX? (There's no such model as a *Mark I* anything in Canons model naming convention.)

Comment: YN-E3-RX is not compatible with the older version of 580EX. The manual says so, I have tested this combo myself as well and confirmed it is not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean the *[Phottix Laso TTL Flash Trigger Receiver (For Canon)](http://www.phottix.com/index.php/en/phottix-laso-ttl-flash-trigger-receiver-for-canon.html)* it *should* work. (Do note that at the link in the previous sentence Laso discloses that the receiver you are considering is not compatible with *Multi flash*. *Multi Flash* is what Canon uses to describe [a sequence of multiple stroboscopic flashes](http://www.the-digital-picture.com/News/News-Post.aspx?News=17540) fired while the shutter remains open for a single exposure. It has nothing to do with the number of flash units you are using but rather with the number of flash pulses used for a single frame.)

The Yongnuo YN-E3-RT is a clone of the Canon ST-E3-RT and is supposed to be able to control any radio receiver that can be controlled by the ST-E3-RT. It reportedly works fine with any Canon produced radio receiver built into Canon's RT flashes.

You *might* run into compatibility problems, though, if the YN-E3-RT transmitter and the Laso Receiver are both reverse engineered in slightly different ways. The only way to be sure would be to test the combination. It will most likely work. But if I were in your shoes I'd be sure to order the Laso from a seller, such as amazon, that allows returns for any reason within 15-30 days of purchase. I'd also be sure to test the combination in every conceivable usage scenario for which you plan to use it before the return period is over. For example, you may find that it works as expected in TTL or Manual mode, but doesn't work correctly in [Group mode](http://heysyl.com/canon-group-mode-mixing-modes-on-600ex-rt-speedlites/) (or vice-versa).

Comment: Phottix Laso Receiver is much more expensive than the YN-E3-RX. I wish there is a non-TTL receiver that I can use with YN-E3-RT trigger. My best option is to sell my 580EX and get YN-600EX-RT flash instead.

Comment: @carbotex The question you asked was "Can a YN-E3-RT control a Phottix Laso Receiver?". The answer is that it very likely is. Whether you decide to try it or change flashes instead is an entirely different question.